# Enabling CORS on Express Server deployed via Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, cors

Hi have a fairly basic express set up on firebase, see implementation below:

```
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import router from './router.js';
import cors from 'cors';


const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api', router);

const api = onRequest(app);

export api;
```

Note the `app.use(cors());`. When I make a get request from the client I get a CORS error

Error in console:
[image]

I'm making the request from a next.js frontend using axios within a useEffect hook. The request looks like this:

```
 const {
     data: { linkToken },
  } = await axios.get('/plaid/link-token');
```

Im testing the request via postment and it works fine.

[image]

As you can see from the logs, the function is being envoked
[image]

Any insight on whether my config needs adjustment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error message? It should be in your browser's _Console_ panel

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you are making the request.  We should be able to see that your client code matches your backend code. Also share your function logs that show your function is being invoked.

Comment: @Phil Updated questoin to include error message

Comment: @DougStevenson updated question to show how im making the request. The logs dont show the request because it doesnt maket it that far. They do show the request made from postman

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I messed up in my function call and this wasnt a cors issue at all

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to at least provide details. Somebody else in the future will probably have the same problem, come across this post and throw their computer out the window